# What does `const char* yes[5]` represents in this line of code?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a question about typedef in c++

for example:

```
typedef const char* yes[5];
```

Does typedef gives a alternative name of const char*, so the alternative name of const char* is `yes[5]`? what does `yes[5]` here represents? and how to create two yes arrays and initializes one of the two?

Answer (score 9):

No. This declares a type `yes` which is an array of five `const char *` .

See [this link](http://www.cdecl.org/) and type `const char *yes[5];` inside the text area.

Answer (score 7):

No, this makes `yes` a new name for an array of 5 pointers to constant character data.

The way to think of it is the expression after `typedef` looks like a declaration, and the name in the declaration is instead considered a name for the new type which is the type being declared.

So `typedef int x;` makes `x` be a new name for `int`. This doesn't change with arrays.

Comment: Actually that syntax is an array of 5 pointers to const char, as const char * is the same as char const *

Comment: yes, I agree with Dan F, it should contain 5 pointers to const char, not 5 constant pointers to char